# What's a good, simple, dynamic 3D mesh renderer?

Tags: java, 3d

I want to create a simple game using 3d graphics, and I'm looking for a 
rendering tool. My game will only use meshes that are created dynamically -
they can morph, change number of vertices, and disappear entirely.
Most tools seem like they are designed to use models that don't change 
in the way I need them to, particularly changing the number of vertices 
in the mesh. The other issue is that most renderers (e.g. Java3D and OpenGL) are much more powerful, and thus more complicated, than I need.

I found [a tool from NYU](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/experiments/render/)
and [sj3d](https://github.com/Calvin-L/sj3d), which are almost exactly
what I need, except that they only work for meshes that lie entirely 
in front of the camera, as far as I can tell.

I would prefer a tool that runs in Java, but tools in other languages
would also be very much appreciated. Thanks for any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into Khronos group's glTF 2.0 - might get you the speed and fluidity you need, but in fact not minus the overall power and toolset.

https://www.khronos.org/gltf/

From the resources and examples section of the Khronos page whose link I posted above, I find redcube js - a javascript library for rendering webgl. RedCube is a minimalistic viewer used Khronos glTF 1.0 format.

https://github.com/Reon90/redcube

There are also a slew of other resources aggregated on that page for coders - I personally am not a coder - I'm a 3D generalist.

Comment: Could you please explain more how Maximus could use it, for instance with Java?